# Illegal context for vector clause in simple OpenACC kernel

Tags: openacc, pgi, pgi-accelerator

I'm trying to compile a simple OpenACC benchmark:

```
void foo(const float * restrict a, int a_stride, float * restrict c, int c_stride) {
#pragma acc parallel copyin(a[0:a_stride*256]) copyout(c[0:c_stride*256])
#pragma acc loop vector(128)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
      float sum = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < 256; ++j) {
        sum += *(a + a_stride * i + j);
      }
      *(c + c_stride * i) = sum;
    }
  }
}
```

with Nvidia HPC SDK 21.5 and run into an error

```
$ nvc++ -S tmp.cc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -acc -acclibs -Minfo=all -g -gpu=cc80
NVC++-S-0155-Illegal context for gang(num:) or worker(num:) or vector(length:)  (tmp.cc: 7)
NVC++/x86-64 Linux 21.5-0: compilation completed with severe errors
```

Any idea what may cause this? From what I can tell my syntax for `vector(128)` is legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's illegal OpenACC syntax to use "vector(value)" with a parallel construct.  You need to use a "vector_length" clause on the parallel directive to define the vector length.  The reason is because "parallel" defines a single compute region to be offloaded and hence all vector loops in this region need to have the same vector length.

You can use "vector(value)" only with a "kernels" construct since the compiler can then split the region into multiple kernels each having a different vector length.

Option 1:

```
% cat test.c
void foo(const float * restrict a, int a_stride, float * restrict c, int c_stride) {
#pragma acc parallel vector_length(128) copyin(a[0:a_stride*256]) copyout(c[0:c_stride*256])
#pragma acc loop vector
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
      float sum = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < 256; ++j) {
        sum += *(a + a_stride * i + j);
      }
      *(c + c_stride * i) = sum;
    }
  }
}
% nvc -acc -c test.c -Minfo=accel
foo:
      4, Generating copyout(c[:c_stride*256]) [if not already present]
         Generating copyin(a[:a_stride*256]) [if not already present]
         Generating Tesla code
          5, #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */
          7, #pragma acc loop seq
      5, Loop is parallelizable
      7, Loop is parallelizable
```

Option 2:

```
% cat test.c
void foo(const float * restrict a, int a_stride, float * restrict c, int c_stride) {
#pragma acc kernels copyin(a[0:a_stride*256]) copyout(c[0:c_stride*256])
#pragma acc loop independent vector(128)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
      float sum = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < 256; ++j) {
        sum += *(a + a_stride * i + j);
      }
      *(c + c_stride * i) = sum;
    }
  }
}
% nvc -acc -c test.c -Minfo=accel
foo:
      4, Generating copyout(c[:c_stride*256]) [if not already present]
         Generating copyin(a[:a_stride*256]) [if not already present]
      5, Loop is parallelizable
         Generating Tesla code
          5, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
          7, #pragma acc loop seq
      7, Loop is parallelizable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mat. The spec is particularly vague about this: "When the parent compute construct is a parallel construct, or on an orphaned loop construct, the vector clause specifies that the iterations of the associated loop or loops are to be executed in vector or SIMD mode ... The operations will execute using vectors of the length specified or chosen for the parallel region" so maybe it's possible to make the error message more clear (i.e. "vector length can not be specified for individual loops within parallel block")?